# Search for username substring in pwd string

Tags: bash

Any idea what is wrong with this script? I am trying to check to see if the username is part of the present working directory file path. I have included two different implementations of the same thing, and neither of them work.

```
#!/bin/bash

USER_NAME=$(whoami)

if [[ "$USER_NAME" == *"$PWD"* ]]; then
  echo $PWD
else
  echo "not found"
fi

case "$USER_NAME" in 
  *$PWD*) echo $PWD ;;
esac
```

Also, this does not work either:

```
grep "$USER_NAME" "$PWD"
```

However, this works:

```
echo "$PWD" | grep "$USER_NAME"
```

Any idea what is going on here?

EDIT: This does not work either:

```
if [[ *"$PWD"* == "$USER_NAME" ]]; then
  echo "found"
else
  echo "not found"
fi
```

or even this:

```
if [[ $PWD == $USER_NAME ]]; then
  echo "found"
else
  echo "not found"
fi
```

or any other combination of `*` or quotes that I have tried so far.

EDIT2:

finally got it, have to use this:

```
if [[ $PWD == *$USER_NAME* ]]; then
  echo "found"
else
  echo "not found"
fi
```

Comment: I have referred to many different questions on SO and SE which address this, which is where I got the examples, but have not found a clear answer as to why these examples do not work.

Comment: Just check that one duplicate, and compare it with your codes... Sloppyness and programming don't mix well together.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: You don't see it either? Lol. I will post an answer...

Comment: Oh. Backwards. *facepalm*.

Comment: I have already tried swapping the arguments and it still does not work. Have also tried various combinations of quotes and *, none of them seem to result in matching username within the PWD path

Answer (score 1):

There are two things, what you search for, and what you search in. You're mixing the two in your examples.

```
if [[ "$USER_NAME" == *"$PWD"* ]]; then
           ^------swap----^
```

And this greps in the *file* named by the contents of `PWD` clearly won't work, because `PWD` is a directory, not a file:

```
grep "$USER_NAME" "$PWD"
```

Comment: I had already tried swapping them but it still did/does not work

Comment: Nonsense. Post the value of the variables which it fails with.